# Flutter constants File with Provider package

Tags: flutter

I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to set up some constants (mainly strings).  Currently I'm using a constants.dart file that just has the const variables defined in there and import it whenever it's needed. No class or anything, just a blank dart file.  This works, however, I recently implemented localization using the Flutter Intl plugin in Android Studio.  I got everything to work and can do something like this `S.of(context).settings` and it gets the translation from the correct file.  My problem comes with some constant list of strings I have in my constants.dart file.  I use them in many places for option selects.  They look like this:

```
const playType = [
  'RP/Story Focused',
  'Battle/Combat Focused',
  'Puzzles and Challenges',
  'Exploration/Travel',
];
const length = [
  'One Shot',
  '2-5 Sessions',
  '5-10 Sessions',
  'On-going Campaign',
];
```

I cant change the the strings to the Intl reference because there is not context to be passed.  Not sure how to set up a class that is loaded but not sure how to set that up and use the Provider package to serve it up.

EDIT:
heres the Constants file.  Calling this with the provider is fine.  The issue comes when I need to use the localization on the strings in the lists

```
import 'package:scryer/generated/l10n.dart';

class Constants {
  Constants._();
  static final instance = Constants._();

  static List<String> playType = [
    S.of(context).rpstoryFocused,//need a reference to a context
    'Battle/Combat Focused',
    'Puzzles and Challenges',
    'Exploration/Travel',
  ];
  static const length = [
    'One Shot',
    '2-5 Sessions',
    '5-10 Sessions',
    'On-going Campaign',
  ];
}
```

Heres how I call the constants on the actual page.  Its a button that on press goes to a new screen that is either a multiselect checkbox list or single select radiobutton list.  I pass the constants as an argument for the list

```
MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
  return MultiSelectScreen(
    args: MultiSelectArguments(
      label: S.of(context).selectPreferredPlayStyle,
      options: playType, //this is the constants list reference
      selections:
        profile.playType,
    ),
  );
})
```

The easy solution is to not use a constant and just create the lists in these spots, only used like twice i think, but better practice is to pull it out since its being used multiple times

Answer (score 0):

you can try.

```
class Constants {
   final BuildContext context;
   Constants(@required this.context);
 //  static final instance = Constants._();     // to make class a singleton

static  const playType = [
    'RP/Story Focused',
    'Battle/Combat Focused',
    'Puzzles and Challenges',
    'Exploration/Travel',
  ];
static const length = [
    'One Shot',
    '2-5 Sessions',
    '5-10 Sessions',
    'On-going Campaign',
 ];

}
```

Then, at the root of your project you should provide this class like;

```
void main() {

/** WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized() is required in Flutter v1.9.4+ before using any plugins if the code is executed before runApp. */
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

     runApp( Provider( 
       create: (context) => Constants(context),
       child: MyApp(),
       ),
   );

}
```

You will be able to access these constants in any BuildContext anywhere down the widget tree as follows;

```
final Contants constants = Provider<Constants>.of(context);
```

you get the length constant like; `constants.length`

Comment: there is still no reference to the context in the constants file, so cant use the localization in the lists to translate the strings in the list

Comment: there isnt an error thrown, the localization needs a context variable, so need to be able to access the context in the Constants class.  Editing question with the constants file

Comment: will the edit work? if not will try to extend Constants class with a state class to provide some build context

Comment: Nope, get the warning only static members can be accessed in the initializers

Comment: Can we see where you are calling the locale with context? Note that context is available only in the `initstate` and/or build method.

Comment: made some edits for how the constant lists are being used in the app